# Filtering a collection with offset in grails

Tags: grails, collections, dynamic-finders

I'm trying to filter a collection in grails with findAll so I only get the instances with a certain value in his field "estado".
I have something like this:

```
trabajos.findAll({it.estado.equals( "Pago")})
```

The problem is I dont know how to paginate the returned collection.
I took a look at grails documentation and found this

```
Book.findAll(Map queryParams, Closure whereCriteria)
```

but when I try it

```
trabajos.findAll([offset: 0], {it.estado.equals("Pago")})
```

I get the following exception

```
No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.findAll() is applicable for argument types:       (java.util.LinkedHashMap, com.publidirecta.PersonalController$_show_closure2) values: [[offset:0], com.publidirecta.PersonalController$_show_closure2@a6bdb0] 
Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), find(), find()`
```

Is this a why to achieve some sort of pagination this why or would I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are muss 2 things: grails and groovy.
`Book.findAll(Map queryParams, Closure whereCriteria)` - is a finder in database, it's grails thing and you can pass max param in it.
But in `trabajos.findAll({it.estado.equals( "Pago")})` you are trying to find in list. It's groovy thing. See more details [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html) and [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections)

If you try to get objects from database, use like this

`Book.findAll(Map queryParams, Closure whereCriteria)`.

If it's a list of objects use something like this:

```
def filtered = trabajos.findAll({it.estado.equals( "Pago")})
def result = filteredList[offset..offset+max < filtered.size() ? offset+max : filtered.size()]
```

Comment: Ok, I see the error. Now I tried to achieve it inside the closure with maxResults(3) and firstResult(0) but this also dosent work